# Apache Camel and FTP processing

Tags: file, ftp, download, apache-camel

we are trying to build up a process server in Camel. We have several client, providing files via FTP. We have to mirror the ftp files, but we would like to download only the files we do not have already. The server of the clients have to keep untouched, so no changes are allowed, only reading.

```
String to = DownloadFolder.getInstance().getDownloadFolder() + File.separator + "test";
                from("ftp://user@server/downloads/&binary=true&stepwise=false&localWorkDirectory=/tmp")//
                        .process(new ProcessCheckForDownload(to))//
                        .to("file://" + to + "?keepLastModified=true")//
                        .to("jms:queue:FTP_FILE_RECEIVED");
```

The problem is, that ftp is downloading the file before I can check for downloading. When setting download=false, I would be able to check for downloading, but how to move on. I can't process a single file for downloading, at least right now. Next problem is, that this job is broken, because jms would like to get the temp-file, and not the final file.

Perhaps anybody has a hint on how to go on with this problems.

Answer (score 1):

The file and hence the FTP compomponent has this feature built in. It's called an [idempotent consumer](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html). Basically, you can turn on this feature by `idempotent=true` on the endpoint.

The default idempotent repo does not survive server restarts, as it stores data about already read files in memory. You can use persistent idempotent repos instead, such as the [File based idempotent repository](http://camel.apache.org/file2#File2-Usingafilebasedidempotentrepository) (or some [database repos](http://camel.apache.org/file2#File2-UsingaJPAbasedidempotentrepository), or your custom class).

There are plenty of examples on the [file](http://camel.apache.org/file2) page, as the FTP component inherits from File, the same thing applies (mostly).

Btw, the `download=false` feature is available for Camel 2.11 only, which is not yet released.

Comment: Unfortunately the feature idempotent=true actually only checks for the filename. When the file was updated it does not recognize these changes. But this is one request we have.

Comment: Yeah this is a good idea to allow people to customize the key and specify to include timestamp etc. I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6006

Comment: @ClausIbsen: I tried using indempotentKey with 2.11-SNAPSHOT and the sftp scheme but camel complains about an unknown parameter. Does the change only affect the file component or should I be able to use indempotentKey with sftp?

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to extend the method isValidFile of GenericFileConsumer.

```
protected boolean isValidFile(GenericFile<T> file, boolean isDirectory) {
        if (!isMatched(file, isDirectory)) {
            log.trace("File did not match. Will skip this file: {}", file);
            return false;
        } else if (endpoint.isIdempotent() && endpoint.getIdempotentRepository()**.contains(file.getAbsoluteFilePath())**) {
            log.trace("This consumer is idempotent and the file has been consumed before. Will skip this file: {}", file);
            return false;
        }    
        // file matched
        return true;
    }
```

We have to generate our own key containing size and date of last change. I think that will do the trick.

```
.contains(file.getAbsoluteFilePath()+":"+file.getFileLength()+":"+file.getLastModified())
```

All we have to do is create our own consumer.

Comment: I logged a JIRA ticket at ASF to improve this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6006